# Finding IP Address for IPhone

Tags: iphone, ip

I am working on IPhone. I want to know how to find a ip address of a iphone through USB/3G not on wifi.
I am aware of seeing IP if it is connected through WiFI.(Going through settings and looking under Wifi)
But i need IP through USB / 3G. what i did means i used personal hotspot and i connected my iphone to PC through usb. I got an IP.
But when i added one more Iphone with same hot spot enabled and connected through USB i am getting like unidentified network.

By using whatismyip.com site i am getting an ip . but i cant do anything with it. I am unable to reach my iphone with the provided ip of that site.

So can anyone kindly provide information on how to look for IP of multiple Iphones connected to same PC.

The purpose is to communicate to muliple iphones with their IP's.

Thanks  a million in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the responses are not completely correct. In a 3G/4G network every device gets an IP address, but THAT's NOT the IP address that you see when going to sites like www.whatismyip.com. That's the address that the Telco presents to the external world, not the device IP address.

Telcos such AT&t, Verizon, Telefonica and similar assign a "private" IP address that is only valid in their network. This is similar to the internal IP address that you have in your phone when connect to the house wireless, but if you check in www.whatismyip.com you get the external IP address of your wireless router (You can check that those are different addresses). What Telcos do is known as NAT or PAT. The reason is that the current version of IP has a very limited number of available IP addresses, and all those million of devices cannot get public IP addresses (like the one you see in whatismyip.com). Actually several devices share that external IP address.

Unlike Android devices where you can get the IP that the telco assigned to the device, iOS does not present that information to the user (unless you jailbreak the device or have an App).

Although the address that whatismyip presents is not your real IP, it is the one that the external world recognizes so it suffices for most purposes.

Comment: This screws up ip2location isn't it?

Comment: Not only is the IP assigned the phone private and behind NAT to the public IP assigned by the telco, if you enable your iPhone or iPad to be a hotspot, it adds ANOTHER level of NAT as it hands out addresses over WiFi to other devices. My company has software for file transfer through "challenged" networks that can push out through one level of NAT but not through two levels! Furthermore there is NO WAY you can control port forwarding on either of those NAT translations.

Comment: As an update to most people, this is generally no longer as true as many telcos are now providing IPv6 for cell service and the connection can and is often handled by the IPv6 connection (this holds true for at least AT&T a few others). Though, sourcing the iphone's address is still a challenge unless you have jailbroken your phone.

Answer (score 5):

What you see on `whatismyip.com` is the IP address you get from your mobile provider, on which it depends what kind op IP you get. Very often 3G networks are NATted, meaning that you get an IP address from the range `10.0.0.0/8` which cannot be reached from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Using www.whatismyip.com should definitely give you the correct address?

What address did you get when it came back?

How did you verify if this was your iPhone's address? I assume you don't have a firewall installed on your iPhone? Hmm, other thing is your provider is doing some kind of filtering, NAT-ing, or other tomfoolery. If you don't mind me asking, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to run some kind of server-style app on your iPhone? Or do you just want to get a connection between the iPhone and a server - might be easier to initiate the connection from the iPhone side.

You should check if it's at your provider's IP block range - an online whois check should tell you that (www.whois.net).

How did you test whether this was your iPhone's address?

Other option is just to have your iPhone hit a server that you control (using 3G), and check the server logs.

Or just make things easier, and use an app to tell you - e.g. iStat:

http://bjango.com/iphone/istat/

which will give you your cell (3G) IP address as well.

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Actually i need to operate my iphones through vnc viewers.When i connected my phone through USB i got an iP and i given that ip and port in vnc viewer it got connected and worked but when i connect other mobile unable to find its ip and not able to connect through Vnc viewer.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, so we can help answer your question better - you're using a VNC Viewer on your desktop to connect to your iPhone? So you're running a VNC server on your iPhone? Is this Veency? Hmm, you'll need to verify whether your 3G provider actually exposes a public IP, or they're not doing some kind of filtering/NAT-ing - you might be better off doing a reverse SSH tunnel *from* the iPhone to your server, then routing your VNC request over that - does that make sense?

Comment: To simplify my Question I had two IPhones(Having Veency Installed) and I had Vnc Viewer. Is there any possible way to access both mobiles parallely? Can you give a Solution or alternate for doing this job ?Thanks for Your valuable Info

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of IP addresses:

Private IP address (your device IP that you get it from your home Wi-Fi router or from your Teleco provider router to speak to those two routers).

Public IP address (your home Wi-Fi router and/or from your Teleco provider router which they will use it to allow you to speak to another person on the Internet).

**NOTE: Without Public IP address, you cannot speak to people who are on the Internet.

Now both (your home Wi-Fi router or your Teleco Provider router)they have something called DHCP, or Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol. This protocol is used to allocate private IP address to anyone connected to local network (either home Wi-Fi or Teleco provider).

That means both (home Wi-Fi router and Teleco provider router) have one single IP address called Public IP address to allow you to speak to outside world, but first they need to give private IP address to able you to speak with them (your home Wi-Fi router and your Teleco provider router).

If your iOS connected to your home Wi-Fi, then you will have a Private IP address:

1- Go to settings.

2- Click on Wi-Fi.

3- List of Wi-Fi networks will be appeared.

4- Click on your Wi-Fi network name (known as SSID).

5- Click on the blue circle of the exclamation mark on the right side of your Wi-Fi name.

You will see your Private IP Address there very clearly.

Now if your iOS device is not connected to any Wi-Fi network, but it connected to your Teleco provider, then you cannot see your private IP address.
I am sure there is a way to see your Private IP address that you got it from your Teleco Provider DHCP. You have to search from internet or ruin your device by jailbreak it.

For the Public IP Address (no matter if you are connected to your home Wi-Fi or your Teleco Provider), go to your internet browser (e.x. google chrome) and type: "What is my ip address". The result will be between your hand in fractions of seconds!

Now Back to your question:

If you connected two iPhones to your PC and both have hotspot enabled, that means your PC USB ports will handle two IP Private addresses because your iPhones will act as your home Wi-Fi router.

if you have windows OS in your laptop, then go to windows CMD terminal and type:

ipconfig

the CMD prompt terminal will give you number of IP address, there are your two Private IP addresses from your iPhones.

Now if unidentified network message still there, open RUN in your windows OS and type [ ncpa.cpl ], it will take you to network connection setting section, right click on one of your iPhones networks and disable it, keeping the other enabled.

I hope it is crystal clear now.

Answer (score 0):

When the phone is the hotspot for the Telecom cellular provider it actually being used as a Router therefor if you connect laptop to that hotspot you can open network setting on the laptop to view its tcp/ip settings and see the ip of the laptop and the ip of the Router which is the IP of your Phone.
The Ip is a private one, you can ping to it or do what ever you want.

Example of connecting Iphone to Mac Xcode wirelessly:

1. share personal hotSpot from your phone.
2. connect your laptop to your phone private network using wifi, search for the ssid you set in your phone and set a correct password.
3. in Mac go to System prefences->Network->wifi connected->Advanced->Tcp/Ip
   copy Router Ip - this is your Iphone private Ip.

In order to connect Xcode to Iphone wirelessly you first need to connect the phone with usb, open window->device and simulators, select your phone and set checkbox "connect via network"

Now if the phone is disconnected from the Mac and the private network is shared as explained, you know the phone Ip, then you can select the phone in Xcode (it remember phones that were connected), open window->device and simulators, select your phone , click on it to get menu of options, select "connect with ip", provide the ip you saw as "Router" previously.
Thats all, hope it'll help somebody.